# MySQL ERR in Express Back-End Server

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, error-handling

I am facing an MySQL err while I am executing a query on my Express server.

My code is as follows.

```js
module.exports.generateDailyWords = async function () {
  try {
    // generate the shape of word combination for the day
    var shape = generateRandomNumbers();

    // retrieve 4 words from the dictionary
    var q_1 = `
            SELECT word 
            FROM new_dic 
            WHERE LENGTH(word) = ?
            ORDER BY RAND() 
            LIMIT 1
        `;
    var first = await excuteQuery(q_1, [shape[0]]);
    var word_1 = first[0].word;

    var q_2 = `
            SELECT word 
            FROM new_dic 
            WHERE LENGTH(word) = ? 
            AND word LIKE ?
            AND word != ?
            ORDER BY RAND() 
            LIMIT 1
        `;

    var second = await excuteQuery(q_2, [shape[1], word_1[0] + "%", word_1]);
    var word_2 = second[0].word;

    var q_3 = `
            SELECT word 
            FROM new_dic 
            WHERE LENGTH(word) = ? 
            AND word LIKE ? 
            AND word != ?
            AND word != ?
            ORDER BY RAND() 
            LIMIT 1
        `;

    var third = await excuteQuery(q_3, [
      shape[1],
      word_1[word_1.length - 1] + "%",
      word_1,
      word_2,
    ]);
    var word_3 = third[0].word;

    var q_4 = `
            SELECT word
            FROM new_dic
            WHERE LENGTH(word) = ?
            AND word LIKE ?
            AND word != ?
            AND word != ?
            AND word != ?
            ORDER BY RAND()
            LIMIT 1
        `;

    var forth = await excuteQuery(q_4, [
      shape[0],
      word_2[word_2.length - 1] + "%" + word_3[word_3.length - 1],
      word_1,
      word_2,
      word_3,
    ]);
    var word_4 = forth[0].word;

    // save the combination into the database
    var combination = JSON.stringify([word_1, word_2, word_3, word_4]);

    return combination;
    // return '["jube","juicy","ender","ywar"]'
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err, "err while generating daily words");
    await this.generateDailyWords();
  }
};
```

So this function - generateDailyWords is responsible for retrieving a combination of 4 words which meets a certain condition. I run this regularly(will be daily, for now every 10 min for testing.) and sometimes I got this error which implies that retrieving a word from db has failed.

Any idea regarding this issue?

p.s. I haven't got much experience with back-end development so would appreciate if someone can let me know an efficient way for error handling, like best practice for writing error handling helper function.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'word')

I tried to log retrieved data, which sometimes gave me undefined variables.

Comment: You're never accounting for queries that return zero rows

Comment: Does `generateRandomNumbers()` return an whole integer and what are the min/max values it returns? For example if it ever returns a 0 or 500 then of course you won't find any words.

Comment: ah, right but it returns integers from 3-6.
Thanks.
I think this can be the reason.
Like I got a dictionary and it has no word which starts from x and has the length of 4.
In this case the retrieved data is an empty array.
Yep. @Phil is right. Maybe.

And guys I am also hoping your suggestions regarding the efficient err handling  practice in back-end server.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be the reason. Like I got a dictionary and it has no word which starts from x and has the length of 4. In this case the retrieved data is an empty array. Yep. @Phil is right. Maybe.